# Drawing an outline around the non-transparent part of a texture

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, textures

Tinkering with the feature set for a new game, i'm considering including a PVP gameplay mode. Nothing like NI after kicking the AI so smithereens :). iSomething only. Willing to restrict to modern devices.

One option I would consider to differentiate the characters for each player on the map would be to add 'on the fly' a 2-point outline of different colours to the characters of each player (others options exist, but have weight considerations for the resources).

I have not found on here (nor elsewhere for that matter) any very useful answers to this kind of requirement, nor am I an GL expert by a far cry. If any one of you could point me in the direction of some tutorials, I would greatly appreciate. TIA

Comment: Are the characters textured sprites, or 3d models? If sprites, is adding outline data to the source textures an option?

Comment: Sprites. As mentioned, there are options. Current estimates put that app around 320Mb. If i double up texture resources, one with a 'red' and another with a 'blue' outline, well it seems a bit much. This is why i was looking for some way to do this at run-time (albeit a potential performance penalty, yet unquantified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't recommending that you necessarily put the outlines into separate textures. What I was imagining was that you have a sprite with a region that is all `alpha = 1.0`, surrounded by a transparent region of `alpha = 0.0`.

One idea could be to draw a couple pixel wide ring around the opaque region with something like `alpha = 0.5`.

If you then want to draw your sprites without a border, you can just alpha test for `alpha > 0.75`, and the border will not appear. If you want to draw a border, you can alpha test for `alpha > 0.25`, and use a fragment shader to replace all pixels with `0.4 < alpha < 0.6` with a colored border of your choice.

This becomes more difficult if your images use partial transparency, though in that case you could maybe block off the range from 0.0 to 0.1 for alpha metadata like the border.

This would not require any additional textures to be used or increase the size of any of the existing resources.

Comment: ah... did not understand your suggestion in the first place. Currently have the basic alpha=1 surrounded by alpha=0, and are adding manually the 2 points. I'll check with Mr Art whether his tool allows controlling the alpha channel when contouring. If yes, one step closer, then figure out the shader thing and how to convince cocos to do that in a ccAnimation. brb.

Comment: yep, we can control alpha channel when outlining.

Comment: was a bit of work, did not need to toy with CCAnimation, the shader program is propagated from frame1 to all the following ones. Anti aliasing not so obvious. Will probably toss the ball back in Mr Art's hands :) , but that was a great idea.